# Change a WHILE loop to a FOR loop at C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am developing a c program. I am using this struct:

main.h:

```
#define LONG_CADENA 22
#define NUM_CADENAS 5
#define formato "%22s%22s%22s%22s%22s\n"
#define indi_format "%22s"
typedef struct Agenda
{
   char*nom[NUM_CADENAS];
   struct Agenda *ant,*sig;
}ag;
```

I have this function to show the object Agenda:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"
ag *mostrarAgenda(ag*act)
{
   unsigned i=0;
   void*ini;
   ini=act;
   while(act++->sig)//ma1: Reescribir esta línea utilizando el bucle for
      for(;i<NUM_CADENAS;i++)
         printf(indi_format,act->nom[i]);
   printf("\n");
   getchar();
   return ini;
}
```

I need change de WHILE loop to a FOR loop, but I am new using C and I dont know how I could do it.

Some help please?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to change it (and you already have one for loop)?

Comment: Try `for(;act++->sig;)`. But why? Is this a homework?

Comment: Because I am doing some test to learn C. Thanks!!

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun's comment is exactly what you are looking for but, do you understand that using `act++` is incorrect? It will working only if act is a static array. You should use `act = act->sig`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the while loop as `for(;act->sig;act++)` or `for(;act++->sig;)`. There is no performance difference between them. Not sure why you wanted this. Hope this helps.